# Signalk Custom Plugin not showing on the WebApps

Tags: node.js

I deployed my plugin inside **/home/pi/.signalk/node_modules/my-plugin** and it´s not showing or starting with the server

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out,

Publishing on npmjs with the keyword: **signalk-category-instruments**

Signalk server was able to list and install with no problem.